# Excel VBA Replace characters in cells that contain html code

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in 3 different columns that I want to place in a column of cells that contain 22000 - 24000 characters of html code each. I was able to execute successfully with fewer characters in the column of cells that contain the html code. Is it possible to replace data in the column of cells that contain 22000 -24000 characters of html code each?

And I use a VBA program to do this.

```
Sub GoodREPLACETeleModule()

' <PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE>
For MY_ROWS = 1 To Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value = Replace(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE", Range("AF" & MY_ROWS).Value)
Next MY_ROWS

' <PUTIMAGEHERE>
For MY_ROWS = 1 To Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value = Replace(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTIMAGEHERE", Range("AF" & MY_ROWS).Value)
Next MY_ROWS
End Sub
```

I have "PUTIMAGEHERE" and "PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE" placed within the 24000 lines of html code but it does not reach it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following, does the message box always say it is successful, even for characters greater than 24,000.  If not, which data points fail exactly and at what point.  You can review these data sets to verify that the overall length will not be greater than the limit.

```
Sub GoodREPLACETeleModule()

    Dim wFind As Long

    ' <PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE>
    For MY_ROWS = 1 To Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox "Row " & MY_ROWS
        wFind = InStr(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE")
        If wFind = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Nothing to replace"
            Else
            a = Len(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value): b = Len(Range("AF" & MY_ROWS).Value)
            Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value = Replace(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE", Range("AF" & MY_ROWS).Value)
            wFind = InStr(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE")
            If Not wFind = 0 Then MsgBox "Replace Failed"
            If Len(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value) < a + b - Len("PUTDESCRIPTIONHERE") Then
                MsgBox "The replace did not happen successfully"
                Else
                If Len(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value) > 32766 then 
                    Msgbox "Too many characters"
                    Else
                    MsgBox "Replace succeeded, old string was " & a & " characters, new string is " & Len(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value) & " characters."
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next MY_ROWS

    ' <PUTIMAGEHERE>
    For MY_ROWS = 1 To Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox "Row " & MY_ROWS
        wFind = InStr(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTIMAGEHERE")
        If wFind = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Nothing to replace"
            Else
            a = Len(Range("R" & MY_ROWS).Value): b = Len(Range("AF" & MY_ROWS).Value)
            Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value = Replace(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTIMAGEHERE", Range("AF" & MY_ROWS).Value)
            wFind = InStr(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value, "PUTIMAGEHERE")
            If Not wFind = 0 Then MsgBox "Replace Failed"
            If Len(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value) < a + b - Len("PUTIMAGEHERE") Then
                MsgBox "The replace did not happen successfully"
                Else
                If Len(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value) > 32766 then 
                    Msgbox "Too many characters"
                    Else
                    MsgBox "Replace succeeded, old string was " & a & " characters, new string is " & Len(Range("P" & MY_ROWS).Value) & " characters."
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next MY_ROWS

End Sub
```

Unfortunately there are [Excel Limits](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa)
as to how many characters can be contained in a cell.

Comment: But 24000 is not the limit per cell.

Comment: No, that's true, but suppose you have a cell that has 24,000 characters, and you are replacing a word in that cell with text from a second cell that has 24,000 characters.  Perhaps I misunderstood, but this is what I understood you were doing in your example.  The new combined text would be roughly 48,000 characters which is greater than the limit of 32,767 characters.  What you might be able to do instead, is take the newly formed string and store it in a list, or a file, or broken up into two cells.  But if the combination exceeds the 32,767 limit, it cannot be stored in a single cell.

Comment: No. The second cell contains only 1 to about 50 words. That still will not exceed the cell limitation. Did you try my code? I need to figure this one out.

Comment: I tried to use the `Replace` on a cell with more than 24,000 characters and it worked for me.  Of course to run your code properly, I would need your workbook, but I would suggest instead adding some code to notate what is happening.  I will edit my answer with a diagnostics accordingly.

Comment: Did you use html code in the cells that contain the data that will be replaced?

Comment: No, I do not have the html code in question.  If you can give me a test data to use, I could try that, but I have used "dummy" text because I do not have your exact test data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97325/discussion-between-demetri-and-erc).

Comment: I am in chat right by the way. I uploaded some test code.